# Google app engine - Using gcs-client to read/write file to gcs in the background thread

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using ServletContextListener to do the background thread. I designed this thread is called every hour. I tested with local file and every thing work normally.

But when changing to use google app engine to read/write file in google cloud storage, I received the NullPointerException:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Operation not allowed in a thread that is neither the original request thread nor a thread created by ThreadManager
>   [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.api.NamespaceManager.set(NamespaceManager.java:90)
>   [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.makeKey(LocalRawGcsService.java:311)
>   [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.makeKey(LocalRawGcsService.java:305)
>   [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.getObjectMetadata(LocalRawGcsService.java:397)
>   [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.dev.LocalRawGcsService.readObjectAsync(LocalRawGcsService.java:459)
>   [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.requestBlock(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:107)
>   [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.(PrefetchingGcsInputChannelImpl.java:88)
>   [INFO]  at com.google.appengine.tools.cloudstorage.GcsServiceImpl.openPrefetchingReadChannel(GcsServiceImpl.java:126)
>   [INFO]  at com.lottery.base.Utils.getGCPInputStream(Utils.java:458)

The function getGCPInputStream(String file) as below:

```
public static InputStream getGCPInputStream(String file) {
    GcsFilename fileName = new GcsFilename(Constant.BUCKET_NAME, file);
    GcsInputChannel readChannel = gcsService.openPrefetchingReadChannel(fileName, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);

    return Channels.newInputStream(readChannel);
}
```

I also tested with the sample code and it work fine.

Can anyone tell me what's my problem? I spent many hours to research but have no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a current limitation in the App Engine Standard Java environment. Currently, if you want to call App Engine APIs (com.google.appengine.api.*, which is the case here as per the stack trace you provided), you must call those APIs from a request thread or from a thread created using the ThreadManager API. This is documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/runtime-java8#threads).

To read/write files to Cloud Storage from a background thread, you'll need to create it via the [ThreadManager API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/ThreadManager).